# Serving files for download with Symfony3 and Flysystem

Tags: php, download, symfony, flysystem

### Introduction

I am using:

- Windows 10 Pro
- XAMPP with PHP v7.0.9
- Symfony v3.1.6
- Doctrine v2.5.4
- StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle [[1]](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) in order to
  manage Tree structure.
- OneupUploaderBundle [[2]](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle) in order to Upload files
- OneupFlysystemBundle [[3]](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle) for filesystem abstraction

### Setting up

I did setup the tree structure (that represents directories and files) and file upload with `OneupUploaderBundle` and `Flysystem` endpoint.

File upload is organized to upload to folder named `data` that exists in project root folder. Uploading is working fine and even paths with custom sub-directories for different uploads work (for example `data/project_001/test1.txt` and `data/project_002/test2.txt`)!

### Problem

I need to serve files that users had uploaded earlier.

At the moment

- I am getting error (with controller ending 1)

  ```
  The file "Project_9999/2_Divi/bbb.pdf" does not exist
  500 Internal Server Error - FileNotFoundException
  ```
- and error (with controller ending 2)

  ```
  Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class League\Flysystem\File could not be converted to string
  500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
  ```

Note that `$exists` return `true` - so file is definitely there!

### Code

relevant part of config.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            storage:
                type: flysystem
                filesystem: oneup_flysystem.gallery_filesystem

            frontend: blueimp
            enable_progress: true
            namer: app.upload_unique_namer

            allowed_mimetypes: [ image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif ]
            max_size: 10485760s

oneup_flysystem:
    adapters:
        my_adapter:
            local:
                directory: "%kernel.root_dir%/../data"

    filesystems:
        gallery:
            adapter: my_adapter
```

Controller action

```
<?php

public function projectDownloadFileAction($file_id, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:FileTree');
    $ultra = $this->get('app.ultra_helpers');

    $selected_file = $repo->getFileTreeNodeByIdArray($file_id);
    $item_name = $selected_file[0]['item_name'];
    $item_extension = $selected_file[0]['item_extension'];

    $activeProject = $this->get('session')->get('active_project');
    $activeProjectSelectedNodePath = $this->get('session')->get('active_project_selected_node_path');
    $item_file_name = $item_name .'.'. $item_extension;
    $complete_file_path = $activeProject['secret_path'] . $activeProjectSelectedNodePath .'/'. $item_file_name;
    dump($complete_file_path);

    ENDING -1-
    ENDING -2-
}
```

Ending 1

```
    $downloadable_file = new \SplFileInfo($complete_file_path);
    dump($downloadable_file);
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($downloadable_file);

    // Set headers
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', mime_content_type($downloadable_file));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $downloadable_file->getFilename()
    ));

    return $response;
```

Ending 2

```
    $filesystem = $this->get('oneup_flysystem.gallery_filesystem');
    $exists = $filesystem->has($complete_file_path);
    if (!$exists)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }
    dump($exists);

    $downloadable_file = $filesystem->get($complete_file_path);
    dump($downloadable_file);

    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($complete_file_path);
    $response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
    $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT);

    return $response;
```

### Update 1

I tried to supply absolute path to the `Ending 1` variable `$complete_file_path, but got only errors. For example:

- `File not found at path: C:\DEV\tree_and_upload\data\Project_9999\1_Viens\test1.txt
  500 Internal Server Error - FileNotFoundException`
- `File not found at path: C:/DEV/tree_and_upload/data/Project_9999/1_Viens/test1.txt
  500 Internal Server Error - FileNotFoundException`

But it did not make any diference - I got access error. Perhaps Symfony is actively restricting access to `data` folder in the root of the project...

### Question

How do one would serve files from `data` folder that is situated in project root folder and using `Flysystem` filesystem abstraction layer with `Local` adapter?

### Conclusion

What am I missing?

Please advise.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Does `$complete_file_path` really contain an absolute path to the file or is it relative to `%kernel.root_dir%/../data`?

Comment: @xabbuh, yes `$complete_file_path` is relative to `%kernel.root_dir%/../data`.

Comment: You will then either have to prepend `$complete_file_path` with `%kernel.root_dir%/../data` when constructing the `BinaryFileResponse` or check if there is something like a `getAbsolutePath()` method in the `$filesystem` object.

Comment: @xabbuh, As it turns out there are no methods to get absolute path to the file in `Flysystem` with `local` adapter. It is proposed to move files somewhere to `web` directory to make them accessible or use streams. Indeed - streams allow to serve files from `data` folder that exists in the root of the project. So I ended up using Symfony's `StreamedResponse` and it works beautifully. Thanks for the help/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Flysystem` with `local adapter` has no methods to get downloadable file path! [It is suggested](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/727) to move or store files in the public `web` folder and retrieve path the same way as with assets.

I ended up using `StreamedResponse` [[1]](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response) instead of `BinaryFileResponse`.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->setCallback(function () {
    echo $downloadable_file_stream_contents;
    flush();
});
$response->send();
```

> How do you get $downloadable_file_stream_contents;

```
$fs = new Filesystem($localAdapter);
$downloadable_file_stream = $fs->readStream($public_path);
$downloadable_file_stream_contents = stream_get_contents($downloadable_file_stream);
```

Comment: How do you get `$downloadable_file_stream_contents;`?

Comment: doing so, you will trigger php event for static files, except if you need a custom logic before delivering the file (ie : authorisation layer),  it is not a good practice, you should consider storing them under the web directory.

Comment: @bruno Yes, I need to protect files in `data` folder and serve them only in certain cirsumstances (users, groups). Shared files are copied and stored in `web` directory.